# How to specify the ingest pipeline

Tags: elasticsearch

In all the elasticsearch examples I've seen so far, every [index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html) request that needs to use an ingest pipeline passes it as **query parameter** like

```
PUT /<target>/_doc/<_id>?pipeline=my_pipeline
```

Is this the only way to use the pipeline when indexing documents? Or are there also other ways to utilize the pipelines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's only one of the options, there are plenty of ways to leverage ingest pipelines. You can also:

- Specify pipeline in [bulk queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#docs-bulk-api-query-params)
- or when [reindexing documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#reindex-with-an-ingest-pipeline)
- or when [updating documents matching a query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query-api-query-params)

You can also define a default pipeline to be used when indexing documents inside an index with the [`index.default_pipeline` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings) and the [`index.final_pipeline` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings), so as not to have to specify it in each indexing request (as in your question).

You can also specify it in the [`elasticsearch` Logstash output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-pipeline) or in the Filebeat `elasticsearch` output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/elasticsearch-output.html#pipeline-option-es).

Comment: Thanks @Val: The `index.default_pipeline` setting will be my friend ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Filebeat [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-udp.html#filebeat-input-udp-common-options) recommends configuring the pipeline as early as possible, in the input. From any filebeat ***input*** method common documentation:

> The pipeline ID can also be configured in the Elasticsearch output,
> but this option usually results in simpler configuration files. If the
> pipeline is configured both in the input and output, the option from
> the input is used.